# Describing the sequence A224239.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, recreational-mathematics

I've been trying to describe mathematically the $n$th term $a_n$ of the sequence [A224239](https://oeis.org/A224239). We get $a_n$ by counting the distinct ways to fill an $n\times n$ grid with squares of smaller integer size, up to the symmetries of the $n\times n$ square. It's much more difficult than I expected when I started playing around with it.

I believe these are the different configurations for $n=4$:

[image]

The OEIS page gives pictures for $n=5$.

> How would you go about describing it mathematically? What's known about the sequence?

(You know what I mean when I say "describe mathematically", right?)

*Thoughts:* I think it's related to [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem). The OEIS gives several related sequences that demonstrate that the one in question gets gigantic very quickly, so is difficult to experiment with (at least for me). I haven't come up with any explicit equations for $a_n$ I'm afraid.

Comment: ah. *"What is the next term in 1,2,3,..."* 4, of course! nope. 13!

Comment: Configs 7 and 11 are equivalent, it seems.

Comment: I just noticed: I've corrected it. Thank you :)

Comment: Analytic Combinatorics may be of help. Try constructing a class of combinatorial objects you require and then apply a transfer function to obtain a generating function which you can solve explicitly or asymptotically.

Comment: Just maybe a representation as trees might lead somewhere, similar as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651317/catalan-numbers-staircase-bijection ?

Comment: OEIS is generally kept quite up to date. What's known about the sequence is probably what's there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: In that case I'm (surprised and) very sorry. Thank you. [This didn't seem up to MO standards so . . . ]

Comment: There is no good reason there should be a reasonable analysis of this count.  Maybe there is a bit better chance to get the count where you do not rule out symmetric repeats.