# Using the Catalan Recurrence to prove tiling rectangles in staircases is a Catalan Object

Tags: combinatorics

The Catalan Recurrence is: $C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}$ where $n\ge 0$ and $C_0=1$. I want to use this recurrence to prove that the number of ways to tile an $n$-sized staircase into $n$ rectangles is a Catalan Object. Here is $n=3$ for example, taken from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651317/716998):

[image]

**Here's what I have so far**:

Choose a rectangle inside an $n+1$ sized staircase such that there are $2$ non-overlapping adjacent staircases attached to it (put them in the bottom left corner and top right corner). If one adjacent staircase is size $k$, let the other be size $n-k$. If we tile those adjacent staircases into $k$ and $n-k$ rectangles (there's $C_k$ and $C_{n-k}$ ways to do this), we have $k+n-k+1=n+1$ tiled rectangles. From this diagram, let's identify the adjacent rectangles I speak of:

[image]

The gray is indicating the adjacent staircases and the dotted squares are the size $0$ adjacent staircases. I can see how the terms for $C_3$ are shown in that representation: $$C_3=C_0C_2 + C_1C_1 + C_2C_0$$

**My question**: What else am I missing from my proof? I can't see why each adjacent staircase of size $k$ and $n-k$ will always leave us with a rectangle leftover. And how do I know there aren't any more possible tilings beyond what each pair of adjacent staircases ($C_kC_{n-k}$) is giving us? Do I need to inductively show anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete your proof note that *every* staircase tiling has a *unique* rectangle using the top-left corner square, and this leads to a *unique* decomposition into pairs of smaller staircases and a joining rectangle (white in your picture). Similarly, given the two smaller staircases of sizes $a$ and $b$ we can *uniquely* reverse this process to produce the same large staircase of size $a+b+1$ we started out with.

Thus the process of joining staircases together with rectangles produces all staircases and satisfies the Catalan recurrence.